# Add parameters to a PHP mssql query

Tags: php, sql-server

Given the following query (in the code, NOT a stored procedure); how can I add parameters to the query rather than including the condition values directly in the query? In other words: how can I make this database call secure?

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass); 
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle); 

$query  = "SELECT lastname, firstname, address, phone, email ";
$query .= "  FROM person";
$query .= " WHERE lastname LIKE '" . $lastName . "'";

$result = mssql_query($query);

while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
... etc.
```

Comment: why use `LIKE` without % you may as well use =

Comment: @Lawrence LIKE will do a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 2):

Use PDO to make it secure

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 2):

First of all abandon the outdated extension and use [`sqlsrv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php) instead:

> These functions allow you to access MS SQL Server database.
>
> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or
>   later.
>
> SQLSRV, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft:
>   » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.

After that you get suppport for prepared statements:

```
$dbh = sqlsrv_connect ($serverName, $credentials);
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($dbh, 'SELECT lastname,firstname,address,phone,email FROM person WHERE lastname LIKE ?', array(&$lastName));


if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt))
{
   while(false !== ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
     // do stuff with $row
   }
}
```

Of course if i were i would just use PDO as others have suggested with presents the same interface to all db the extensions it supports.

If youre stuck using `mssql` for some reason then i believe youre also stuck manually escaping all your query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a prepared statement (or just a DAL that will allow you to parameterise your queries!).. One option is to use PDO, specifically with the `PDO_SQLSRV` driver..

When doing this you can prepare your queries in a parameterised form, and pass them in at query time, for example..

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$myServer;Database=$myDB", $myUser, $myPass);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT lastname,firstname,address,phone,email FROM person WHERE lastname LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute(array($lastname));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    ...
```

(note code above should be in an in-place replacement, however it's untested!)

If you have a lot of parameters in your query at some point, it may be best to use named parameters so that you can keep track of them better.