# How can I connect mssql server and get values with php

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I'm a newbie on php and I try to make a calendar for people travel information from db and want to show these info on the calendar's day so my problem is to connect MSSQL Server and take the values form db.My php pages work on localhost(wampp) and my calendar view perfectly but cannot get the value from DB.It does not give an error.But can not pull data.Could you please help me to find my fault.Thanks.

connect.php;

```
<?php
        class DBO   
        {
            private $server = "servername";
            private $db_name = "dbname";


            private $password = "pass";


            private $username = "username";


            private $conn;


            private $database;


            function Connect()      
            { 
                $this->conn = mssql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password)
               or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on " . $this->server);

        $this->database = mssql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->conn)
                    or die("Couldn't open database " . $this->db_name);
            }
     function RunSql($sqlQuery)
            {
                  return mssql_query($sqlQuery);
            }
        }
    ?>
```

query code;

```
<?php
    include_once("db_connect.php");
    $DBO = new DBO();  
    $DBO->Connect();    
    $query = "SELECT ID, TYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM TABLENAME";    
    $query_results = $DBO->RunSql($query)
        or die('Error in $query_menu. Error code :' . mssql_get_last_message() );
        $calendar = array();
    while( $results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_menu_results) )
    { 
    $calendar[] = array('ID' =>$rows['ID'],'TYPE' => $rows['TYPE'],'url' => "#","class" =>'event-important','start' => "$start",'end' => "$end");
    }
$calendarData = array(
    "success" => 1, 
    "result"=>$calendar);
echo json_encode($calendarData);
exit;
?>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're issue is from executing the SQL via...

```
$query_results = $DBO->RunSql($query)
```

...but using it via...

```
while( $results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_menu_results) )
```

Basically, $query_results becomes $query_menu_results.

I use a variant of this to test MsSQL connectivity:

```
<?php

// connect to the server
$dbconn = mssql_connect('SEVER_NAME_OR_IP', 'MsSQL-User', 'MsSQL-User-Password');

if (!$dbconn) {
    $message='unable to connect to the database: ' . mssql_get_last_message();
    die($message);
}


// select the database
if (!mssql_select_db('DATABASE_NAME', $dbconn)) {
    die('Unable to select the database!');
}

// execute a query. NOTE: Never use string concatenation in SQL statements. EVER!!!
$sql = "select * from information_schema.tables;";
$query = mssql_query($sql, $dbconn);


// consume the results
echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th></tr>";
while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($query)) {
 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $row[0];
 echo "</td><td>";
 echo $row[1];
 echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


// clean up
mssql_free_result($query);
mssql_close($dbconn);

?>
```

SECURITY NOTE: Last I check, The [mssql*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) doesn't support prepared statements. Please see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [sqlsrv*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php). [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744490/add-parameters-to-a-php-mssql-query) has good info on MsSQL prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I've reproduced your code and I've found these errors:

- `include_once("db_connect.php");` must be `include_once("connect.php");`
- `while ($results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_menu_results)) {` must be `while ($results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_results)) {`
- `'ID' =>$rows['ID'],` must be `'ID' => $results['ID'],`
- `'TYPE' => $rows['TYPE'],` must be `'TYPE' => $results['TYPE'],`
- missing `$start` and `$end` variables;

**Working example:**

Example is based on your code. I've left your erros in comment. Table definition is just to make working query.

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLENAME] (
    [ID] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [TYPE] [numeric](10, 0) NULL,
    [STARTDATE] datetime NULL,
    [ENDDATE] datetime NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [TABLENAME] (ID, TYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
VALUES (1, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

INSERT [TABLENAME] (ID, TYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)
VALUES (1, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

SELECT ID, TYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE 
FROM [TABLENAME]
```

connect.php

```
<?php
    class DBO {
        private $server = "servername";
        private $db_name = "dbname";
        private $password = "pass";
        private $username = "username";

        private $conn;
        private $database;

        function Connect() { 
            $this->conn = 
                mssql_connect($this->server, $this->username, $this->password) or 
                die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on " . $this->server);

            $this->database = 
                mssql_select_db($this->db_name, $this->conn) or 
                die("Couldn't open database " . $this->db_name);
        }

        function RunSql($sqlQuery) {
            return mssql_query($sqlQuery);
        }
    }
?>
```

query.php

```
<?php
    //include_once("db_connect.php");
    include_once("connect.php");

    $DBO = new DBO();  
    $DBO->Connect();    

    $query = "SELECT ID, TYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM [TABLENAME]";    
    $query_results = 
        $DBO->RunSql($query)
        or die('Error in $query_menu. Error code :' . mssql_get_last_message() );

    $calendar = array();
    //while ($results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_menu_results)) { 
    while ($results = mssql_fetch_assoc($query_results)) { 
        $calendar[] = array(
            //'ID' =>$rows['ID'],
            'ID' => $results['ID'],
            //'TYPE' => $rows['TYPE'],
            'TYPE' => $results['TYPE'],
            'url' => "#",
            "class" => 'event-important',
            //'start' => "$start",
            //'end' => "$end"
        );
    }
    $calendarData = array(
        "success" => 1, 
        "result"=>$calendar
    );
    echo json_encode($calendarData);
    exit;
?>
```

Output:

```
{
"success":1,
"result":[
    {"ID":"1","TYPE":"1","url":"#","class":"event-important"},
    {"ID":"1","TYPE":"1","url":"#","class":"event-important"}
]
}
```