# PHP ODBC PDO bindParam causing "Must Declare Scalar variable @P1"

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, azure-sql-database

Long story short I need to connect to a Micrsoft Azure database using PHP, PDO, and ODBC.  However I am unable to use parameters in the query without getting the error below (I have removed some information).

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@P1".
RequestId: TDS;;7
Time: (SQLExecute[40000] at /ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:259)'
```

Here is my code:

```
    // Establish connection
    $db = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $lastName = '%{Bank2}%';

    // Option 1 - Does not work
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE lastName LIKE ?";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute([$lastName]);
    $results1 = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $error1 = $prep->errorInfo();

    // Option 2 - Does not work
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE lastName LIKE ?";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->bindParam(1, $lastName);
    $prep->execute();
    $results2 = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $error2 = $prep->errorInfo();

    // Option 3 - Does not work
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE lastName LIKE :lastName";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName);
    $prep->execute();
    $results3 = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $error3 = $prep->errorInfo();
```

I have tried adding the param type to the binding `$prep->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR)` and that doesn't resolve anything

I know that my connection is good because the below query works fine and returns results:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE lastName LIKE '%Bank2%'";
    $prep = $db->prepare($query);
    $prep->execute();
    $results = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Any ideas with why this is not working?

This is running on PHP 7.4.5 using the PHP installation instructions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

```
./configure --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local
```

Comment: It seams that you have some statements error for the parameter settings. Please ref the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-php#update-data. It gives the example of query/update with parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the artile but it doesn't seem to help.  This is a SQL Server database not PostgreSQL.  It won't connect. @LeonYue

Comment: Hi @aceithamer, sorry for post the wrong link, please ref this example:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/integrate-azure-sql-database-with-php-website/.

Comment: Hi @sceithamer, hope you're doing well, do you get any progresses?

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have resolved this issue, welcome to share the details to us, we can learn from you.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can ref this example: [Execute a prepared statement with question mark placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

You also could ref the answer in this question:[Add parameters to a PHP mssql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744490/add-parameters-to-a-php-mssql-query), other's gave more guides for us.

HTH.